# insert query not working

Tags: php, mysqli

can you assist me with this question 
this is adding two rows in same table. i am new to all this can someone tell me what's wrong here i got an error "Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object"

```
$p1fname=trim($_POST['p1fname']);
         $p1lname=trim($_POST['p1lname']);
         $p1email=trim($_POST['p1email']);
         $p1ahe=trim($_POST['p1age']);
         $p2fname=trim($_POST['p2fname']);
         $p2lname=trim($_POST['p2lname']);
         $p2age=trim($_POST['p2age']);
         $p2email=trim($_POST['p2email']);

        $player="INSERT INTO player (team_id, first_name, last_name, age, email)VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $playerquery=$db->prepare($player);
        $p = $playerquery->bind_param('issisissis', $team_id, $p1fname, $p1lname, $p1age, $p1email, $team_id, $p2fname, $p2lname, $p2age, $p2email);

        if($p){
                $playerquery->execute();
            echo 'player record added ---';

        }
        else{ 
            echo 'player record not added---';

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**replace 'ssssss' with 'sssss'**

in above case you add one more 's' in argument

Also,

**used "d" for number, "f" for float or double value**

Comment: i fixed my question pls check again

Comment: check box field creating trouble.. how to bind it?

Comment: why do you check `cfname` only I would check if they are all set, since they are all required

Comment: html 5 checks all so i dont need to

Answer (score 0):

You trying to add 6 parameter. Only need 5 parameter.

This section:

```
$q = $query->bind_param('ssssss', $name, $cfname, $clname, $phone, $email, $tc);
```

Try this:

```
$q = $query->bind_param('sssss', $name, $cfname, $clname, $phone, $email);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = $query->bind_param('ssssss', $name, $cfname, $clname, $phone, $email, $tc);
```

in above case ,you have passed $tc which you are not using in insert queries.Please check .